# mmap /dev/random

Tags: devices, mmap

Why is it that I cannot mmap `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` on Linux?

I get errno 19 which is `ENODEV`.

When I try the same code with `/dev/zero` it works.

```
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    assert (fd > 0);

    void* random = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FILE, fd, 0);
    int err = errno;

    assert (random != MAP_FAILED);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot `mmap()` `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`. Nor can you `seek()` them for that matter. And as a general rule, you cannot `mmap()` unseekable things. Pipes are another example of things you cannot `mmap()` because they are not seekable.

`/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` are fundamentally stream-based, sequential access, devices. They produce bytes on demand when you read them. Random access to these devices has no meaning. `mmap()` implies random access.

Comment: It seems like an interesting problem to solve, at least for `/dev/urandom`. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What "problem" would you solve? What random access semantics would you confer on `/dev/urandom`? For example, what would it mean to read the 42nd byte of `/dev/urandom`, then read the 46378th byte, then read the 42nd byte again? Would the 42nd byte still have the same value? Random access to these devices seems non-sensical.

Comment: @Celada's answer is so clear. However, it is probably interesting to note that `/dev/random` being a stream device is more likely a question of practicality rather than a conceptual problem. "Would the 42nd byte still have the same value?", both would make sense. An old random value would still be random as long as there is no observable pattern in the observed array of bytes. A new random value would obvously be random.